# What is internal set property in c#?

Tags: c#

I just came across an unknown concept of c# for me.
Can anyone tell me what the purpose of an internal set property is?
What is its use?
I know internal keyword is used for working within an assembly.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you have a property with an internal set accessor (and public get accessor) it means that code within the assembly can read (get) and write (set) the property, but other code can only read it.

You can derive the above information by reading about the [internal access modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal), the [public access modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Also, you can read about [Restricting Accessor Accessibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx).

Comment: +1, Additionally i might want to add to your answer that i have seen internal sets used in two scenarios: 1.) to "hide" stuff, which is probably not a good way to do it and mitght point to a design flow and 2.) unit testing purposes

Comment: UrbanEsc I agree that this seems to point to a design flaw, most times you see it. I just ran into this in some code I'm working with, and it appears to be the source of a dependency with another class (being internal so it can overcome access restrictions of private.) You have to wonder why people choose methods such as this over something much more obvious.

Comment: @JuniorM Other code would be another assembly. Code in the same assembly but a different namespace could still access it.

Comment: `Internal` seems like a good concept in theory because it supports encapsulation but, in practice, it will break inheritance if you have to extend something in a assembly you don't own.

Comment: I had issues with Internal Set and Json Serialization/MVC complaining of missing properties.. Took hours to find that VS defaults to internal set when adding properties using helper. Some properties were missing in the serialization so i dont use it anymore

Answer (score 23):

Suppose you're designing an API for use by other programmers.  Within this API, you have an object `Foo` which has a property `Bar`.  You don't want the other programmers setting the value of `Bar` when they reference your assembly, but you have a need to set the value yourself from within your API.  Simply declare the property as such:

```
public class Foo
{
   public string Bar { get; internal set; }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

[Properties in C# 2.0](http://en.csharp-online.net/Fields_and_Properties)

In C# 2.0 you can set the accessibility of get and set.

The code below shows how to create a private variable with an internal set and public get. The Hour property can now only be set from code in the same module (dll), but can be accessed by all code that uses the module (dll) that contains the class.

```
// private member variables
private int hour;

// create a property
public int Hour
{
  get { return hour; }
  internal set { hour = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If a property setter is marked with the internal access modifier, only classes that reside within the assembly can set the property.

```
public string MyProperty { get; internal set; }
```

Answer (score 4):

given a property declared `public string MyString {get; internal set;}` this means that

- you can **read** the property's value **from anywhere** withhin your application (`public string MyString`)
- but you may only **write** a new value to the property from **inside the assembly** in which it is declared - or from friend assemblies. (`internal set;`)

Answer (score 2):

It means that the property can only be set by code that resides within the same assembly as the class delcaring the property.

Answer (score 2):

It is a construct which allows the value of a property to be set only by code within the same assembly.

Answer (score 1):

it is mostly used with constructors like

```
public class CustomerConfig
{
     public string CustomerName { get; internal set; }
     public CustomerConfig(string customerName)
     {
        this.CustomerName = customerName;
     }
}
```

By this way, you can preset some parameters and make them readonly for other assemblies in your code.