# C# Why dictionary allows property setting though the property is internal set

Tags: c#, properties, access-modifiers, collection-initializer

I'm using fluent validation API for writing validations.

I came across a `internal set` property on `ValidationContext` class.

```
public class ValidationContext {
        public Dictionary<string, object> RootContextData { get; internal set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

I came across the internal set property in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7187849/1551730). So, I can set the value of a dictionary like this

```
var rowItemContext = new ValidationContext();
rowItemContext.RootContextData.Add("ab", new object());//this works
```

The above code to add an item to the `RootcontextData` works.

But the following line to directly assign another dictionary to RootContextData results in an compile time error.

> Property or indexer 'ValidationContext.RootContextData' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

```
rowItemContext.RootContextData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "ab", new object() }
            };
```

So, to add a dictionary of items to context data I have to loop over the dictionary to add. I'm surprised to see why the first one works but not the direct assignment.

Comment: In the first example you are NOT assigning a new object to the `RootContextData` property. You are calling `Add()` on the existing property.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that you got confused as to what counts as "setting" a property.

Generally, you are only `set`ting the property when you use the `=` sign. When you use the assignment operator, you are *actually* giving the property a new value.

`Dictionary` is a reference type, so the property stores a reference to the dictionary object. The value of the property in this case, is the reference pointing to the dictionary.

When you call `Add`, you are just modifying the dictionary object, not the property's value. The property's value still points to the same dictionary object so it remains unchanged.

When you use `=` and creates a new dictionary, you are trying to change the reference stored in the property to some other reference. This counts as `set`ting a property, so you can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are several moments:

1. You use internal set, so you can set property only inside your assembly. see also: [What is internal set property in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187821/what-is-internal-set-property-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. In the second case you use [Collection Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-a-dictionary-with-a-collection-initializer). It sets property with new value (new dictionary initialized with key `"ab"` and value `new object()`)
3. If you get such exception that you try to do this outside your assembly. Use `Add` method.
4. From design perspective: don't use public properties that can mutate internal state of your object. Incapsulate it.